# How to compile this open source project using Cairngorm framework?

Tags: flash, frameworks

http://code.google.com/p/red5/source/browse/flash/trunk/classes/org/red5/samples/publisher/?r=4103#publisher

Looks like MVC to me,but I'm not sure if that's the exact framework used.

**UPDATE**

Now I know it's using the Cairngorm framework,and I've downloaded all the source files,how can I generate a `.swf` file?

**UPDATE 2**

How can I know the exact version of Cairngorm used?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Flex compiler at all?  Or did you come across Flex and Cairngorm at the same time.  Flex is a web client language from Adobe.  Cairngorm is a framework (library) for the Flex language.

Answer (score 2):

Cairngorm, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cairngorm_(Flex_framework)

Comment: I've downloaded all the source files,how can I generate a `.swf` file?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you may be under a mistaken impression. Cairngorm is a framework; so you don't compile the project by running Cairngorm, you use Cairngorm in conjunction with the other code, and compile all of it using something like either Flash Builder, Flex Builder, or the open source compiler that Adobe produces.

The version of Cairngorm which is being used for this project, is included in the trunk of the project under "lib":

http://code.google.com/p/red5/source/browse/flash/trunk/?r=4103#trunk/lib

It's got an annotation to the checkin that says that the version of Cairngorm is 2.2.1.  So to compile this, check out *everything* from the trunk on down, and open it up in Flash Builder/Flex Builder, and then build the .swc using that. Or, failing that, go to http://opensource.adobe.com/flex, and get the Flex SDK which probably will work with this project (if it uses anything Adobe has proclaimed as proprietary, like charts, then Adobe wants you to purchase the proprietary parts first.)

Answer (score 0):

> Now I know it's using the Cairngorm
>   framework,and I've downloaded all the
>   source files,how can I generate a .swf file

I wasn't able to look at the application long because of internet 'rules' here at work, but at first glance it looked like a Flex application.  You'll have to find the main Application file, set it as the 'application' in your flexBuilder settings and compile the thing.  You may have issues with swcs if you don't compile cairngorm from source (for flex sdk mis-matches) but once you have all your library projects in place, this should help you get started:

http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/Debugging+Tutorial